# How to Get Selected Value from Dropdown List C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have created simple website asp.net webform using C#. i have code to display data in dropdownlist when page load like this:

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
    items.Add(new ListItem("User", "1"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("Administrator", "0"));
    DropdownList1.DataSource = items;
    DropdownList1.DataBind();
}
```

I call it in page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayData()
    } 
}
```

i try to get value from **DropdownList1** in btnSubmit

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblResult.Text = DropdownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

this result always get value **User** or **Administartor** string. but, it doesn't i want. I wanna get value just from the values in DropdownList1 as **0** or **1**. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try specifying DataValueField of DropDownList1:

```
DropdownList1.DataSource = items;
DropdownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropdownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
DropdownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 11):

One approach is to use the `DropDownList` [**SelectedItem Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the selectedItem(`ListItem`), then use the [**ListItem.Value Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the corresponding value for the `ListItem`.

```
lblResult.Text = DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Value; // Value property Gets or sets the value associated with the ListItem.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToInt32(DropdownList1.selectedItem.value);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!